# Is this expression a PHP bug? 6227020800 % 10 = 4

Tags: php, xampp

Writing some code connected with factorials (counting sum of numbers of factorial) I noticed that 13! modulus 10 equals 4.

```
function fact($n)
{
    if ($n == 0) return 1;
    return $n * fact($n-1);
}

function sum_num($n)
{
    $sum = 0;
    while ($n > 0)
    {
        $sum = $sum + ($n % 10);
        $n = floor($n/10);
    }
    return $sum;
}

$n = 13;
$buff = fact($n);
echo $n."! = ".$buff;
echo "<br>";
echo "Summ ".$n."! = ".sum_num($buff);
```

Output is:

```
13! = 6227020800

Summ 13! = 31
```

But Summ should be 27. I begun search and found that on the first step I am getting 4 instead 0.

```
6227020800 % 10 = 4
```

And I don't understand why?

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit PHP? If you're running xampp, then it's probably 32-bit, and 6227020800 is outside the range of 32-bit signed integers

Comment: Thanks to all. It's just gone out of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6227020800 requires 33 bits. The most siginficant bit gets truncated and you get you the number 1932053504 (modulo 10 of which is 4).
For arbitrary precision math use `bc*` functions, e.g. `bcmod(6227020800, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use bcmath php module instead for this operations.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Just take care that this module uses strings as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, you use a 32-bit version. Here the max value is 4.294.967.296.